# Remove text below barcode in python barcode.py library

Tags: python, python-2.7, barcode

Does anyone know how to remove text below a bar-code? Bar-code is generated using `barcode.py` library. I was trying to check in https://bitbucket.org/whitie/python-barcode  but could not find solution,what properties should be written in barcode saving line in python:

```
ean = barcode.get('code39', str(row['PART']), writer=ImageWriter())
```

Attaching barcode picture with marked line what i would like to remove from barcode generation.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
barcode.default_writer_options['write_text'] = False
```

Comment: For this solution, I get the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'barcode' has no attribute 'default_writer_options'`. A [different solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690993/2121074) worked for me. Default behavior of this library may be different now.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
ITF = barcode.get_barcode_class('itf')
itf = ITF('30573190692203003169482900832115201911297', writer=ImageWriter())
fullname = itf.save('itf_barcode', options={"write_text": False})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you import "barcode", the solution is:

```
import barcode
barcode.base.Barcode.default_writer_options['write_text'] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it appears you can set the attribute `'human'` (human-readable text) to a non-empty string to override the text at the bottom. If this is set to a string with a single blank, `' '`, the text will be empty.

Comment: yes, it works this way but image size does not reduce as it sees empty string bellow. and i need that image accordingly also shrink as there should not be any text bellow

Comment: ean.default_writer_options['text']='' does not work somehow, but managed to move that text up to barcode by  ean.default_writer_options['text_distance']=0